# Visual Studio dynamic arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, dynamic-arrays

I have been programming with GCC for a while
but I decided to start working with Visual Studio instead, because
it is comfortable.
Anyways, the problem is that in Visual studio, dynamic arrays do not really work
like they do in GCC, so i used **malloc** instead.

When printing the 1st value assigned I will get a correct answer.
However, the next values will be wrong, the 2nd value will always be wrong, the third value wrong and I can not figure out why.

For example, when inserting 1,2,3 and try to print the 2nd spot, it gives 5.

```
int main(void)
{
 K1();
 printf("%d\n", p1+1);
 return 0;
]
```

With p1[i] the program crashes.
p1, is int *

```
void K1(void)
{

 int i;

 printf("n1");
 scanf_s("%d", &n1);

 p1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n1);

 for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
 {
    scanf_s("%d", &p1 + i*sizeof(int));
 }
}
```

I can not figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Always check return values of `scanf` family functions.

Comment: Think about `&p1 + i*sizeof(int)` If you declare a pointer why to add it's size of....?

Comment: This is another try out, at first it was just malloc(n1)

Comment: How and where is `p1` defined?

Comment: `printf("%d\n", p1+1);` `p1, is int *` These two statements can't be correct together in a valid C program.

Comment: `&p1 + i*sizeof(int)` that's not what you want. You want `p1 + i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
scanf_s("%d", &p1 + i*sizeof(int));
```

should just be:

```
scanf_s("%d", p1 + i);
```

or better still:

```
scanf_s("%d", &p1[i]);
```

---

You also have a bug in your `printf` statement here:

```
printf("%d\n", p1+1);
```

This should be:

```
printf("%d\n", *(p1+1));
```

or better still:

```
printf("%d\n", p1[1]);
```

---

Also note that [you should not cast the result of calls such as `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), so:

```
p1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n1);
```

should be:

```
p1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * n1);
```

or better still:

```
p1 = malloc(n1 * sizeof(*p1));
```

Comment: Why do you say `&p1[i]` is better than `p1 + i`?

Comment: @PaulR Yes, the scanf_s("%d", &p1 + i*sizeof(int)); is a fluke from copying.
Ah i feel freaking stupid for asking this question, can not believe i did not see that

Comment: @cad: I would say the array notation provides a clearer representation of the programmer's intent, but it's a matter of personal preference/style, and I know some people still like to think in terms of pointers and offsets.